# How do I repace any combination of "O"s with zeros in long list of part numbers so that I can create a synonym list?

Tags: excel-formula, replace, grep, spreadsheet, number-formatting

We have a list of part numbers that have various alphanumeric combinations. There are no "O"s contained in these part numbers whatsoever, only zeros. However, a customer will sometimes see a part number and assume that the zeros are Os and enter them as such in our search field. THis returns no result.

To remedy this, we have a list of "synonyms" set up to attempt to catch such errors (AJO-9000 = AJ0-9000). However some combinations of zeros and Os have slipped through the cracks.

Here is an example. The part number "00h-1038-k0" can be mistakenly written as:
o0h-1038-k0
0oh-1038-k0
ooh-1038-k0
o0h-1o38-k0
o0h-1038-ko
o0h-1o38-ko
0oh-1o38-k0
0oh-1o38-ko
00h-1o38-ko
00h-1o38-ko
00h-1o38-k0
ooh-1o38-k0
ooh-1o38-ko
ooh-1038-ko
ooh-1o38-ko

We've attempted a to catch the obvious ones manually, but I'm sure there's a formula of some kind that can generate all combinations of a part number that contains zeros to multiple version with "O"s automatically into a spreadsheet that we can then upload to our search as synonyms of those numbers. Any ideas on how I can do this?

I tried a find/replace in excel (all 0s to Os), but combinations of random 0s distributed throughout the part numbers which have no pattern or limit to their length makes this very tricky.

Comment: In stead of a synonym table why not validate the search input and replace any O's at that point with zeros, then do the search?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "upload to our search"?  Am I correct that you do not have the data in Excel, nor do you search the data with Excel.  Rather you are looking to use Excel to create the synonyms, which will then be uploaded into some other system where the searches are conducted?

Comment: @RetiredGeek The search engine will not be able to discern the differnce part numbers entered from other query's such as product names, chemical combounds, etc., so validation isn't an option.

Comment: @Max R Correct, the dev team requested an excel sheet of synonyms for them to upload. I'm not sure what "system" they are using from that point forward.

Comment: @ratsurfer - so, was below what you were hoping for / does it solve the issue? (see updated answer - this took me 5 hrs! lol - should get a life, anyways, hope it helps if anything; recommend VB soln but there are other things I need to invest my time more wisely in... Br,)

Answer (score 0):

*REVISED*

Screenshot(s)/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9hIxGsRxZO-Pqmlg-Eg?e=eOszmn) refer:

Throw this function in:

```
=LET(hh_,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(B2),1,1),kk_,MID(B2,hh_,1),tt_,IFERROR(IF(1*kk_=0,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(B2)),""),""),a_,SEQUENCE(LEN(B2)),b_,MID(B2,a_,1),c_,TRANSPOSE(b_),n_,SUM(IFERROR(1*(1*b_=0),)),o_,DEC2BIN(SEQUENCE(2^n_,1,0,1)),p_,REPT("0",n_-LEN(o_))&o_,aaa_,MID(p_,SEQUENCE(1,n_,1,1),1),bbb1_,MID(B2,aaa_,1),ccc1_,SUBSTITUTE(aaa_,1,"O"),aa_,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(B2),1,1),xx_,MID(B2,aa_,1),ii_,IFERROR(INDEX(ccc1_,SEQUENCE(2^5,1,1,1),MATCH(tt_,FILTER(tt_,--(tt_<>"")),0)),xx_),IF(MOD(hh_,LEN(B2))=0,ii_&",",ii_))
```

[image: Table of all combinations of 0s and omegas]

This returns an array which cannot be handled directly by textjoin / `filterxml` in the same function due to limitations with these and compounding complexity of the function.

For convenience I include a comma in the final column - you may wish to remove, unless you wish to join results together in which case this might be useful - e.g. using `textjoin` etc....

```
=TEXTJOIN("",1,C3#)
```

[image: Final output]

*Still feel VB would be best; power queries/'unpivoting' method is the only other method I'm aware of.  Albeit your Q unique in that one also has to contend with placement in relation to non-zero/'fixed' characters.*

As a bonus feature (like waiting until 8th min after soundtrack finishes for a special feature song ☺) - above linked file has part of the working VB solution in Module 1 - but its incomplete so didn't publish here.. :)

Comment: It appears you may have solved the riddle! Pardon my ignorance, but could you explain how I make this work? For example, do I list all the (correct) part numbers in column B, then paste the formula in column C and it generates the synonyms? If so, maybe my Excel for Mac isn't doing it.

Comment: np - still trying to understand issue/proposed solution myself tbh - all I've done is show you how you can take a string and replace every capital O (omega) for a 0 (zero).... you say that the users often mistake the latter for the former - then presumably enter the entire string with Os (omega) in place of correct 0s (zeros) right?  If so, you have a spreadsheet with what users have entered - and some of these will have the incorrect string values (i.e. they will contain Omega instead of zeros) - is that right/have I understood correctly?

Comment: .. assuming I have understood above -- and assuming you intend to simply rectify / correct what users have entered (after they have done so/at later point) - then take list of user entries and past my formula next to that list (update cell references obviously - since my formula points to cell above, better would be pointing to adjacent cell/column to left / right - i.e. wherever you insert user list) - and drag formula down - voila

Comment: However, if you intend for this to be a 'live' kind of sanity check (ie. that notifies/corrects user on the fly/as and when they input something incorect - so that you don't get any errors of this nature) - then you need to have formula present in cell adjacent to the one being populated by user - you could throw in if statement to notify 'no' if wrong, 'yes' if valid e.g. - using my preivous formula [which would require updating cell references as before] you could have:  *=LET(x_,MID(C3,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(C3),1,1),1),y_,IF(UNICODE(x_)=79,0,x_),z_,TEXTJOIN("",0,y_),if(z_<>C3,"no","yes"))*

Comment: let me know - Stackoverflow may advise / refer us to separate chat forum (tend to do this with lots of comments - happy to continue there if that happens/else will continue/pursue here until then! :) )

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't very clear, but I would need the entry in the opposite direction, meaning I have a column of part numbers with the CORRECT implementation (only zeros), then the next column over would have a comma delimited list of every implementation of that part number with the INCORRECT entry (Os in place of zeros). My example above would list 15 possible combinations. A number such as AH0-1234 would have only one. Thank you for your dedication.

Comment: Or, a column of correct numbers in column A, with the incorrect ones in Column B (correct number repeats on each corresponding row)

Comment: Ahhhhh - np - I didn't register/click that you had actually shown every combination from the first ~6 char string... so is that process (listing every combo) automated - oh nevermind I gather this is what you're asking for - nice Q - let me read once more and have a good think.,  I like these kinds of challenges.  every combo questions can be tough - I mean calculating the number of combos is a straigtforward (or at least used to be back at uni lol) stats Q - listing those options is another story... yeah if you separated the combinations with commas and put an "or" at the end of that string..

Comment: could've helped a little (I should actually read the Q better - my bad).. can we go back to the problem though - your ultimate goal is to 'catch' these 0s - do you necessarily need a list of what you call 'synonyms' *(i.e. every combination of the same 6 char string that comprises at least 1 error in relation to the Omega character being inserted in place of the valid numeric digit 0)*?

Comment: I mean - you know you can catch such an error and even recommend the correct variation with a simple formula/function....  or is the a deeper purpose in question RE: the combinations?

Comment: Alright fine - lets see .. brute force or VB... VB nice and neat... let me give both a go..

Comment: When you get a high enough rating - go ahead and vote up or down depending upon whether I get this (one way or other - i.e. vb/brute)...

Comment: I got all the way to the step with C9 and it has an "Error in Value". Am I able to display screenshots in the comments so I can show you? The steps previous to this seem to work fine.

Comment: Just updated to something far more succinct.robust - sorry! check the latest out and see if you get better luck with this method.,.... this was friggin hard I'll tell you that!.

Comment: if it works for you consider accepting the solution, if not don't - for future users...  Br,

Comment: PS - you shouldn;t encounter same issue with this version (surprised you get that with older solution - suspect it had something to do with spacing of the columns - that was a dirty /gough method that required too much manual intervention / space requirements were hectic -  latest solution much better./ dynamic and strictly speaking is a 'standalone' function (the final bit is for completeness, but could be committed).  if you get stuck again advise you try to access/.downloadn file - this might require a free  Mircosoft a/c - I can see anything about you and vice versa)

Comment: But in any case, I always advise ensuring Macro security settings block content in downloaded workbooks - if you feeling uncomfortable with downloading wokrbok with macro let me know and I'll remove it and re-uploaed .xlsx file.   Br,

Comment: That works. Than you! Sorry for being such a noob on Stackoverflow. I sent a response last night, but it didn't go through.

Comment: no worries - noob or no noob this wasn't an easy problem - at least it wasn't for me (and I don't really see any other attempts - so couldn't have been terribly easy or too many others I suspect :)..  glad to hear it - you should accept or decline the answer for future users (tick if accept. or I guess leave as is - unless the restrictions dont't allow you to until you have higher even accept - although I thought it only worked like that for the upvote/downvotes ... not a big deal though - just saing   anyways have good evening!

Comment: Yeah, my score isn't high enough for an upvote to register.